# Dual Axis Chart in Tableau from different measure

Tags: charts, axis, tableau-api

I have two stack chart divided by year and the stack chart is divided by two values. I want to show percentage difference between the year among the values. I have tried using calculated field and dual axis but get stuck after adding one field. Let me attach a snapshot for more clarification. In the image I want to plot below two calculated field in the stack chart as well to show percentage difference between the year.

[image]

Comment: Have to tried to created calculated filled and put it on "Label" in Cards that would show difference in year on label.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking but try this:
1. Remove your [Differnce in Others_cal1] pill from the above graph.     2. Drag the same pill to the far right hand side oside of the stacked bar chart and drop it. This should then add the variable as a second(dual) measure.                                                                                                     3. Selecting the new axis, right click and chose "edit axis" and check the sync dual axis.  graphhttp://www.vizwiz.com/2013/03/tableau-tip-displaying-multiple.html